# deploy solr-3.4.0 to jboss-5.0.1

Tags: jboss, solr

I want to deploy solr-3.4.0 in jboss-5.0.1. the steps i followed is:

1. I copied the solr.war file from D:/apache-solr-3.4.0/example/webapps to jb0ss-5.0.1/serve/default/deploy
2. I changed the web.xml file inside solr.war. I enabled the D:\apache-solr-3.4.0\example\solr

I am getting HTTP Status 404 - /solr. Any ideas to solve ?

Comment: what is the war file name? Rename it to solr.war

Comment: my war file name is solr.war. still its not working. am i missing some step.

Comment: +1 Your question was usefull for solvin a problem...thx :)